Passing last IP octet to a host alias and have it added to complete full proxycommand with ip address
I wish to have this all done in the ssh config file for a specific user. The site has hard-coded ip addresses into there various software and using the naming convention is not really an option.
Host bast.aws1.prod
  HostName bastion.aws1.chaos.com
  User chaos

Host *.aws1.prod
  User chaos
  Proxycommand ssh bast.aws1.prod -W 192.168.10.`echo %h | cut -d. -f1`:%p

Host bast.aws2.prod
  HostName bastion.aws2.chaos.com
  User chaos

Host *.aws2.prod
  User chaos
  Proxycommand ssh bast.aws2.prod -W 192.168.12.`echo %h | cut -d. -f1`:%p

So if I run the following command:
ssh 169.aws2.prod it should execute within the proxy command "ssh bast.aws2.prod -W 192.168.12.169:22"
but it executes "ssh bast.aws2.prod -W 192.168.12.echo %h | cut -d. -f1:22" instead.
What is the best way to pass the last octet to the value within the proxycommand?
Alternative ways are welcome.

Try using: cut -d'.' -f1

Tried that Jay, no joy. Strange how it works fine with a name on other servers. Maybe I will look if there is a function to convert all to a ip address - not sure if there is a string variable interfering.

Where is the 169:22 coming from?

169 will be the last octet I specify thus replacing the * in the *.aws2.prod option I type and :22 is the default port for ssh which is included by default.
